# sbt plugin - How to make sure my settingKey is resolve before everything else?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a `settingKey[Level.Value]` which is for the level of logs. I would like to set this value prior to everything else so that my log level is applied to everything.

( I know there is a `setLogLevel` but I would like to be able to set it, only for my Plugin )

If my setting is named `myLogLevel`, I tried to call `myLogLevel.value` inside each of my tasks and settings.

The issue seems to be that if I am not using the value yield by it, then the setting is not executed.

My setting is something like that :

```
myLogLevel := {
  val theValueSetByTheUser = myLogLevel.value
  MyLogLibrary.setLevel(theValueSetByTheUser)
  theValueSetByTheUser
}
```

So what should I do ? Should I call `println(myResultLevel)` everywhere so it is used. It seems silly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution :

You need two `settingKey`.

The first one is : `myLogLevel: settingKey[Level.Value]` .

And consumer of your plugin can set it to whatever in their `build.sbt` and you can put a default value in your settings: `myLogLevel := Level.Info` .

Then, you have a second setting: `myLog: settingKey[Logger]`

which is not exposed to the consumer and you define it like :

```
myLog := {
  createLogOfLevel(myLogLevel.value)
}
```

And in your other task and setting, you can now call:

```
val log = myLog.value
log.info("message")
```